# Vertica: How to create a new column by subtracting two other columns?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a Vertica table named `Start_End` like:

```
|   name |    Started |      Ended |
------------------------------------
| Albert | 1970-01-16 | 1970-06-01 |
|  Barry | 1992-05-01 | 1992-07-14 |
|  Carol | 2001-03-16 | 2001-06-03 |
```

It has about 100,000 rows.

How can I use [`months_between`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/MONTHS_BETWEEN.htm) to subtract `Started` from `Ended`?

The resulting table would look like:

```
|   name |    Started |      Ended | Month_diff |
-------------------------------------------------
| Albert | 1970-01-16 | 1970-06-01 |           4|
|  Barry | 1992-05-01 | 1992-07-14 |           2|
|  Carol | 2001-03-16 | 2001-06-03 |           2|
```

The following will add a blank column:

```
ALTER TABLE Start_End
ADD COLUMN Month_diff INTEGER
```

How can I use [`months_between`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/MONTHS_BETWEEN.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/MONTHS_BETWEEN.htm?zoom_highlight=MONTHS%20BETWEEN

to find out if the behaviour of MONTHS_BETWEEN() (when to return INTEGER, when to return FLOAT, last-day-of-month behaviour, etc) is the one you need.
Otherwise, you might want to DATE_TRUNC() the two operands first, for example, as @Gordon Linoff suggests. Or use TIMESTAMPDIFF(month, ...) instead:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/TIMESTAMPDIFF.htm?zoom_highlight=timestampdiff

That said, try this for size:

```
ALTER TABLE start_end
ADD month_diff INTEGER DEFAULT MONTHS_BETWEEN(ended,started)
```

Good luck ...

Comment: I get the error: `[Vertica][VJDBC](3457) ROLLBACK: Function MONTHS_BETWEEN(varchar, varchar) does not exist, or permission is denied for MONTHS_BETWEEN(varchar, varchar)`

Comment: I fixed that by wrapping the columns in CAST(col AS DATE):

`ALTER TABLE start_end
ADD month_diff INTEGER DEFAULT MONTHS_BETWEEN(CAST(ended AS DATE), CAST(started AS DATE))`

Comment: In Vertica, you can just go, for example `'2020-04-21'::DATE`. The double colon is the cast operator. And if your input columns are varchars, but always contain dates in format 'yyyy-mm-dd' or 'mm/dd/yyyy' or 'dd.mm.yyyy' , then you should maintain these columns as DATEs , not VARCHARs. Then, you would not have to typecast the operands of MONTHS_BETWEEN() ...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want complete months between the dates.  It think this is:

```
select months_between(date_trunc('month', ended), date_trunc('month', started)) - 1 as month_diff
```